# Disabling size classes & app layout in iPhone 6s vs 6

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

My app has size classes disabled.

I've been testing throughout the entire development on my iPhone 6 and making sure that all objects are where they are supposed to be and up to my standard.

However, I recently ran it on an iPhone 6s and it seems like things are all over the place.

How do I build a responsive layout that molds itself to an iPhone 6s as well as an iPhone 6?

I've been using auto layout.

Answer (score 0):

If your app is targeted for iOS 9 use stack views in combination with auto layout. It will allow you to create responsive layout quite easy. First you should check some tutorial about stack view in iOS if you are not familiar with it.